# How to use tr command in subprocess

Tags: python, csv, subprocess, tr

I'm new to the tr command and was wondering how it works? How does the command know which file to operate on? My understanding is the syntax is tr [options] [change from] [change to]. There is no file stated to operate on. I'm trying to create a csv file and want to change "/" to ","

My file starts with:

```
3251/pid/3256/
245/pid/09732/
234541/pid/92/
1/4918,
```

I want to get:

```
3251,pid,3256,
245,pid,09732,
234541,pid,92,
1,4918,
```

I have:

```
subprocess.run(['tr', '/', ',']), stdout = open('outfile.txt.tmp','w'))
```

It starts to run but it never completes and I have to quit every time. Not sure what the error is but I would like to know what my syntax here should be if I want to be running the tr on a file called **infile.txt**

Comment: You are executing `tr / ,` so `tr` is waiting for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any input `tr` waits forever. You need to pass the file contents to stdin:

```
subprocess.run(['tr', '/', ','], stdout = open('outfile.txt.tmp','w'), input=open('foo.txt').read().encode('utf-8'))
print(open('outfile.txt.tmp').read())
```

Output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['tr', '/', ','], returncode=0)
3251,pid,3256,
245,pid,09732,
234541,pid,92,
1,4918,
```